# Why use & (Ampersand) along with column name in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bitwise-operators

I have come across a select statement as below:

```
select column_a, column_b
from MyTable 
Where column_a&1=1
```

column_a original value is 6500.
what does the column_a&1=1 means?

Comment: first bit in 6500 = 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bitwise `AND` operator. doing `someNumber & someOtherNumber = someOtherNumber` will check if the `someOtherNumber` bits are in `someNumber`

```
  1000 1010
& 0000 1000 --+
-----------   +---- same result, the bit is present
  0000 1000 --+

  1000 1010
& 0000 0100 --+
-----------   +---- different result, the bit is absent
  0000 0000 --+
```

6500 in binary is `1100101100100`

doing 6500 & 1 = 1 is equivalent to

```
  0001 1001 0110 0100
& 0000 0000 0000 0001
---------------------
  0000 0000 0000 0000
```

The bit `0000 0000 0000 0001` isn't in `0001 1001 0110 0100`, hence the result `0000 0000 0000 0000`

This operation, of course, can be done on many bits at once :

```
  1000 1010
& 0000 0110 --+
-----------   +---- different result, the bits are (partially) absents
  0000 0010 --+
```

---

A practical example is the permissions access on a file like in an UNIX system.

As far as I remember, the differents rights are *execute*, *write* and *read* and defined as such :

Execute : `0001`

Write : `0010`

Read : `0100`

Am I allowed to write (`0010`) a file with access rights defined as 5 (binary `0101`) ?

```
  0101
& 0010
------
  0000
```

Nope, I'm not.

Am I allowed to read and write (`0110`) a file with access rights defined as 7 (binary `0111`) ?

```
  0111
& 0110
------
  0110
```

Yes I am.

Comment: very comprehensive, appreciate this...